# javascript validate zip regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks guys. I take your advice and modify the script as following. Now it seems working.

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script>
$(function(){
var pat=/^[0-9]{5}$/;
if ( !pat.test(   $('#zip').val()   ) )
{$('#zip').after('<p>zip is invalid</p>');}
})
</script>

zip (US only) <input type="text" name='zip' id='zip' maxlength="5">
```

Comment: if you did not read below, *it makes no sense to `append` anything to an input element*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.val` needs to be `.val()` 
and use `.after()` or `.before()` and not `.append()`

```
var pattern = /^[0-9]{5}$/;
if (!pattern.test($('#zip').val())) {
  $('#zip').after('<p>zip is invalid</p>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

zip is invalid should be enclosed in quotes

and .val needs to be .val()

```
<script>
  pattern=/^[0-9]{5}$/;
  if (!pattern.test( $('#zip').val() ) ) 
  {
    $('#zip').val($('<p>',{html: "zip is invalid"}));
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `.append()` on `<input>` element?

Comment: oh.. yeah, i was just looking at the structure of it.. i'll adjust the code, good eye!

Answer (score 0):

Space it out so you can see what's wrong..

```
pattern=/^[0-9]{5}$/;
if (
   !pattern.test(   $('#zip').val()  ) 
)
{
    $('#zip').after(
         $('<p>',{html: "zip is invalid"})
    );
}
```

`val()` and "zip is valid". Also, the `var` is useless unless within a function scope.

```
(function() {
    var pattern=/^[0-9]{5}$/;
    if (
       !pattern.test(   $('#zip').val()  ) 
    )
    {
        $('#zip').after(
             $('<p>',{html: "zip is invalid"})
        );
    }
})();
```

Now `pattern` is local to that function only and nothing else. In CMS's example it's still a global unless you're taking the snippet and using it in an actual function.

Comment: `.append()` on `<input>` element?